Animated TV show with five girls that have superpowers
I am searching for a old cartoon program, but it's not available anywhere. The name starts with something like "Super" (but I am not sure).
There will be a total of 5 girls would be there in this cartoon who are initially normal students. Then they came to know that they have some powers in themselves. The powers are air, water, earth, fire.... I don't remember the other.
Actually there's another girl (name is Elliot or Elliet or eliat or something like that). A boy character is also there. His aim is to take the girl (Elliot) to another world. He will meet all the six after some episodes of the cartoon.

Hi. Do you remember the country\language? The year\decade it aired in? Was it anime? CGI?

'Sailor Moon' is similar (girls with super powers, a boy character, another world), but it's not a complete fit, I guess. Maybe it's the same genre (anime for girls) at least...

My sister read when little "W.I.T.C.H" (Will, Irma, Taranee, Cornelia and Hay Lin), a Disney Italian Comic that seems to have been adapted in TV Show.

It sounds like W.I.T.C.H.
W.I.T.C.H is about Will, Irma, Taranee, Cornelia, and Hay, who are "Guardians Of The Veil." They are guardians of quintessence, water, fire, earth, and air respectively. The other character you're thinking of is named Elyon, who Prince Phobos is trying to defeat.
Lord Cedric may be the antagonist you're thinking of, who is the general of Prince Phobos. He wants to lure Elyon (who is the lost princess) to the other world of Meridian so Prince Phobos can remain the ruler of Meridian.
It matches your description very closely.
